# How to not render a entire string with jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a blog from start for a homework assignment in Google App Engine in python and I'm using jinja2 to render my html. My problem is that like every blog when an entry is too long; the blog just renders a part of the entry in the main page. I want to do that, when the main page is rendered I took the post from the database and pasted it to jinja. Are there any filters or functions to tell jinja, for example, this string can not be longer than x number?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Look at [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.truncate)

Jinja2 has truncate filter `truncate(s, length=255, killwords=False, end='...')`. Example usage

```
<div>{{ blogpost.text|truncate }}</div>
```

Or

```
<div>{{ blogpost.text|truncate(1024, True) }}</div>
```